# How to pass a "WTF object" in Flask

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

I am using flask to develop a website and now i encountered a problem.
I am thinking whether I can pass a "WTF form" object in flask.
Like,

```
@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
@login_required
def index():
  user = flask.g.user
  form = PostForm()
  return flask.render_template("index.html",
        title="Home",
        user=user,
        form = form)
```

This form, an instance of PostForm, actually will be processed by the following code:

```
@app.route('/note/<int:id>', methods=['POST'])
def note(id):

form = ?(how to get this form?)?
if form.validate_on_submit():
   print id
   content = form.body.data
   currentTime = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d', time.localtime(time.time()) )
   user_id = id
   return flask.redirect(flask.url_for('login'))

return flask.redirect( flask.request.args.get('next') or
        flask.url_for('index') )
```

In the template, I set the *action* to be "/note/1", so it will forward to this address. But the question, how can I get the form created in the function *index*?

I have tried to use *flask.g* (Obviously, it does not work because it's another request). And I also tried to use *global* variable. It failed, either.

Could anyone give me a solution or any advice?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to construct a new version of `PostForm` in your `note` route and use the posted data in `request.form`:

```
from flask import request

@app.route('/note/<int:id>', methods=['POST'])
def note(id):
    form = PostForm(request.form)
    # or, if you are using Flask-WTF
    # you can do
    # form = PostForm()
    # and Flask-WTF will automatically pull from request.form
```

Comment: You don't even need the `request.form` argument if you're using Flask-WTF, it's [automatically populated as a convenience](https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html#validating-forms).

Comment: Thank you so much! It seems like I am still not familiar with the flask and its extensions.

Comment: Do u mean i can just do  form = PostForm()? I don't this is gonna work. Because I tried this way before.